# How to call toYaml and exclude particular key?

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, go-templates, sprig-template-functions

Inside the template I have a fragment like this:

```
props: {{- toYaml .Values.myApp.container.props }}
```

currently props contains 4 children:

```
...
    container:
      props:
        a: ...
        b: ...
        c: ...
        d: ...
```

But I want to exclude `c` on the fly. Is there way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
{{ $myProps := .Values.myApp.container.props }}
{{ $_ := unset $myProps "c" }}
```

Then you can use it, for example:

```
props: {{ $myProps | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
```

which leads to:

```yaml
props: 
  a: 1
  b: 2
  d: 4
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is "$_" ?

Comment: This is explained in official docs: `Note that set returns the dictionary (a requirement of Go template functions), so you may need to trap the value as done above with the $_ assignment.` https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#set. It is also true for `unset`.

Comment: so `$_` is just a variable name ?

Comment: Yes. It is called blank identifier in golang.

Answer (score 2):

Helm includes a function on dictionaries called [`omit`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#omit).

> The omit function is similar to pick, except it returns a new dict with all the keys that do not match the given keys.
> Example:
>
> ```
> $myDict := dict "name1" "value1" "name2" "value2" "name3" "value 3"
> $new := omit $myDict "name1" "name3"
> ```
>
> The above returns `{name2: value2}`

In your case this would mean:

```
props: {{ omit .Values.myApp.container.props "c" | toYaml }}
```

Answer (score 0):

[The docs say](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions)

> This function is equivalent to GoLang yaml.Marshal function, see docs here: https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Marshal

That function *does* support excluding certain fields, however this works by annotating Go types which is not viable here. So you'd need to remove the field before piping the values into `toYaml`.

Helm does provide a [without](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#without-mustwithout) function, however that only works on lists. So you seem to be out of luck here.

A last resort would be to use [`regexReplaceAll`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#regexreplaceall-mustregexreplaceall) on the resulting YAML string, but… do you really want to do that?